# Different file sizes in memory and on disk

Tags: python, pandas

I just wrote a `csv` file using `pandas'` `to_csv` function. I can see that the size of this file on disk is 13GB. I want to read this file back into a `pandas` `dataframe` using `pd.read_csv`. While reading this file in, I monitor memory usage of the server. Turns out that the memory consumed reading this file in, is 30GB+ and the file is never read in. The kernel of my `jupyter notebook` dies and I have to start the process once again.

My question is that why is such a behaviour happening? It's a very simple piece of code to write and read the file, so why are the space requirements different? And finally, how do I read this file in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Use chunks to minimize memory usage while loading.

```
import pandas as pd
chunksize = 10 ** 8
chunks=pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
df=pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)
```

If that doesn't work, this calls the garbage collector inside the for loop, and may have some minor performance improvement

```
import pandas as pd
import gc
chunksize = 10 ** 8
dfs = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    dfs.append(chunk)
    gc.collect()
final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas) question also indicates

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get the error `NameError: name 'process' is not defined`. I believe it needs an import.

Comment: So I used the exact same code and played around a little bit with the value of chunksize, I'm still running into `MemoryError`.
Here's my code:

`chunks=pd.read_csv('filename.csv',chunksize=10000)
f=pd.DataFrame()
%time df=pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)`